# Finding diff to conffile?

Tags: package-management, dpkg

Suppose some package foo...

```
$ apt-get install foo
```

..installs a dpkg blessed **conffile** `/etc/foo.conf` (ie package maintainer version)

Now suppose after the package is installed `/etc/foo.conf` is modifed, perhaps to add a line.

We would now like to get a diff between the package maintainer version of `foo.conf` and the current one (to see what local configuration changes were made).

What's the easiest way to do this?

One way would be to install the package in a chroot jail and then diff it to the clean one.  Is there an easier way?

Answer (score 3):

After you have upgraded your packages, dpkg will save its new configuration file with a `.dpkg-new` suffix (if you chose to keep your own changes):

```
diff -u /etc/foo.conf /etc/foo.conf.dpkg-new
```

If you chose for overwriting your conffiles, it will be renamed and get a `.dpkg-old` suffix:
    diff -u /etc/foo.conf.dpkgold /etc/foo.conf

As tumbleweed said, you can also extract the .deb file. First you need to get the .deb file from somewhere and then you will be able to extract it. If you have not run `apt-get clean` before, you should have a .deb file already available in `/var/cache/apt/archives/` which means that you can skip the `apt-get download` part and adjust the path for `dpkg-deb -x` accordingly.

```
apt-get download foo
dpkg-deb -x foo_<version>_<arch>.deb fs
diff -u fs/etc/foo.conf /etc/foo.conf
```

Answer (score 2):

You could install `etckeeper`. It manages your `/etc` directory with a VCS, automatically committing before and after every time you use apt.

Or, you can extract the deb: `dpkg-deb -x foo.deb foo`, will dump its contents into the `foo` directory.